is there a way to pass down props from parent component to child component
https://github.com/89missions/reactproblem/issues/1 I have posted all three files here please help.
react-dom.development.js:4312  Uncaught Type Error: props.UserName is not a function
at userValue (Editprofile.jsx:14:15)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:25)
at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:3)
at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:7)
at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:5)
at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:3)
at react-dom.development.js:9288:12 this is the error message

i have a problem passing down props from a parent component down to children component. please im aware i can use useContext . buh thats not my problem now. i created a state variable in the parent component and passing down the variable and its function down to its children componet. your text

Please add the actual relevant code to your post here. Any out-going links might go stale for future viewers.

pages/Editprofile.jsx:14 you call the prop setuserName but the prop is passed as setUsername on pages/Profile.jsx:19. watch out for case sensitivity.

It may be due to the way you have named your state variable.
In react naming convention, only components are supposed to have capitalized names like UserName, so when you use {UserName} it may try to render it and hence the error UserName is not a function.
try renaming your state variable (and the prop) to userName (with lowercase u) and see if it helps.
If you need to pass the variable many levels, you may want to use a state management library like zustand to make your life a lot easier than using context.

Question is unclear. So the answer doesn't get to the point.
